# What is the best way to deploy the app for both Google Play and Huawei's App Gallery using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

We already publish multiple apps in Google Play integrated with GMS using Flutter. Right now, we want to publish the existing app to Huawei App Gallery. Currently, the app is integrated with both GMS as well as HMS for push notification and it is working well. To differentiate the app, we sign the apk for App Gallery with a different signature than the Google Play store.

After some research, we found out that the app bundle id needs to end with .huawei suffix to integrate with IAP. We don't use any IAP but might in the future. However, we faced some problems when building the app since GMS's bundle id doesn't use the .huawei suffix. We prefer combining the same codebase for both Google Play and App Gallery.

My question is that is it necessary to include the .huawei suffix for app bundle id released in Huawei App Gallery. If yes, what is the best way to deploy the app for both Google Play and App Gallery using Flutter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is that is it necessary to include the .huawei suffix for
> app bundle id released in Huawei App Gallery.

Please confirm your app category to be released first:

1. For common apps, **.huawei** is not mandatory.
2. For game apps, **.huawei** is mandatory.

In the scenario where the package name of a game app is forcibly changed, you are advised to use multiple channel packaging. Add the **.huawei** suffix to the package name in Huawei channel. Change the package name in **productFlavor** in the **build.gradle** file under the app directory.

```
flavorDimensions "flavor"
productFlavors{
    huawei {
        applicationId "com.huawei"
        dimension "flavor"
    }
    appMarket2{
        applicationId "com.appMarket2"
        dimension "flavor"
    }
}
```

For details about multi-channel packaging, please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor#h1-1581245784585).

Comment: In the case of Huawei's smartphone that has both HMS and GMS, is there a way to differentiate the IAP's status and app's version?

Comment: Hi @HafizMokhtar, Does **IAP's status** mean you want to know whether the IAP of HMS and GMS is available? And **app's version** indicates you want to know the version of your own app?

Comment: I did some research last time when downloading the app from AppGallery, I still have the ability to update the app in Google Play (same bundle id). When updated from Google Play, I lose the app purchase and payment method change to Google Pay. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @HafizMokhtar It seems the app in Google Play does not integrate Huawei IAP. The simplest solution is to use different package names for Google Play and Huawei AppGallery, and then they will not affect each other. If you don't change the package name, this issue will keep existing. :(

Comment: The app version is installed on the phone (regardless of the source). If the AppGallery has a new version of the app (the package name is the same but the signature is different, and the versioncode is later than the existing version on the mobile phone), the AG displays a message indicating that the app has a new version but does not automatically upgrade the app. If the signatures are different, the system will uninstall and then install it. In this case, the data will be deleted.

Comment: @zhangxaochen for Flutter app. Can we use G+H approach where only generate one APK and release on both GP and AG?